# What is Rails qualified reference mean in Rails Guide?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1O3td.png)

It confused me so long when i read this in rails guide, according to this, does the User class below can be loaded?

Because there is no User constant in Admin, so rails assume User is a relative constant,thus the class User can be loaded?It's so confusing

```rb
class User
end
module Admin
end
Admin::User # can load User?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until Ruby 2.5 it used to work

```
Admin::User
```

Would be loaded since Ruby would look for User under Admin's scope, and then when it couldn't find it - it would keep looking in the top level scope (Object - and there User is indeed defined).
But this behavior is [deprecated in newer Ruby versions (2.5+)](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11547), so no - it won't work.

Comment: Oh, my... that's it.My local ruby version is 3.0,and i have tried 2.7.3 and 2.5.5 but all failed.

Answer (score 0):

No Ruby on Rails would not be able to load `Admin::User` in your example because `Admin::User` is not defined in your example.